# Изменение значения атрибута класса изменяемого и индексируемого типа если имя атрибута доступно через строковую переменную/константу

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Коллеги! Дан класс, в котором есть атрибут типа список или словарь. Задача: изменить один из элементов этого списка/словаря, но при том, что название атрибута доступно нам через строковую переменную или строковую константу. Я знаю один способ с применением встроенного объекта `__dict__`:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.attr: dict[str, int] = {'key1': 5,
                                 'key2': 7,
                                 'key3': 42}


my_class = MyClass()
attr_name = 'attr'
print(my_class.attr['key2'])

my_class.__dict__[attr_name]['key2'] = 12
print(my_class.attr['key2'])
```

**Вопрос:**
Насколько такой способ является допустимым? Есть ли другие, более адекватные способы?

Comment: Для операций с атрибутами лучше использовать встроенные функции [`delattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#delattr), [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr), [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)

Comment: Не лучше ли getattr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для операций с атрибутами лучше использовать встроенные функции [`delattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#delattr), [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr), [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr), [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

Причина в том, что объекты в Python не обязаны хранить атрибуты в `__dict__`. Производные типы могут переопределять доступ к атрибутам, перегрузив методы [`__getattr__`, `__get_attribute__`, `__delattr__`, `__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access). Встроенные функции `{has,get,set,del}attr` умеют обращаться с такими объектами.

Для вашего примера:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.attr: dict[str, int] = {'key1': 5,
                                 'key2': 7,
                                 'key3': 42}


my_class = MyClass()
attr_name = 'attr'
print(getattr(my_class, attr_name)['key2'])

getattr(my_class, attr_name)['key2'] = 12
print(my_class.attr['key2'])
```

Результат

```
7
12
```

В примере я не использую `setattr` для обновления значения атрибута, так как словарь хранит данные по ссылке, и можно присваивать значения ключам напрямую `getattr(my_class, attr_name)['key2'] = 12`.

Comment: Благодарю, решено!